# Filtering SSHD Logs

Tags: ssh, log-files, syslog

I'm just wondering about the best way to filter my sshd logs. The problem is that I monitor my boxes over SSH using Nagios and Cacti. They both connect every 5 mins and this clogs up my log files with loads of entries making it difficult to do a quick 'tail' to see what's going on.

I'd like to have all logins from my monitoring user (on a specific IP) logged in a separate file.

Ideally I'd avoid installing syslog-ng or similar. I would have to set this up on a variety of Ubuntu, CentOS and FreeBSD machines (running a variety of OpenSSH versions), so it will make life easier if I can do this without additional software.

Any recommendations on how to achieve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You could do something like this:

```
tail -f logfile | grep -v "some\.ip\.address\.to\.ignore"
```

or

```
tail -f logfile | grep -v "some\.ip\.address\.to\.ignore.*user-name"
```

Answer (score 1):

you could pass your syslog file to pipe like this

```
mkfifo /var/log/pipes/pipe1
```

and then

read that with script that will remove strings you don't want
like this:

```
cat /var/log/pipes/pipe1 | grep -v "login from xxx.xxx.xxx" | while read LINE
do
  echo $LINE >>/var/log/ssh.log
done
```

Comment: aha!
yep that's more or less what i was looking for. something not requiring extra packages or a huge amount of setup.

although maybe i should also be thinking about more advanced analysis and intrusion detection such as ossec.

cheers everyone!

Comment: we are company making log analysis software for ISP's :)

Answer (score 0):

Yoy can try [ossec](http://www.ossec.net/), it has a very good log analysis.

Answer (score 0):

[Swatch](http://www.linuxjournal.com/article/4776) is a good program for tailing and filtering log files, even supporting colorizing lines.  There's a Debian/Ubuntu package for it too.